# How to use baresip CLI to play an audio file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, sip

I'm trying to make my home automation system make announcement calls via `SIP` so that when an event occurs, the system would call to a specified number, play back an audio file and hang up.

I have found out that I could use baresip for this. I have installed baresip from Ubuntu repositories, set the SIP account configuration and I'm able to make a call interactively from the CLI. Unfortunately, I have not been able to play an audio file. I have read that I need to use the `aufile` module, but I have no idea how.

So, any tips on what kind of command I should invoke to make a call and play back an audio file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify aufile and wave file (make sure format is matching) as audio source:

audio_source            aufile,/tmp/test.wav

https://github.com/baresip/baresip/blob/main/modules/aufile/aufile.c#L20.

Other similar module is avformat, capable of playing both audio and/or video from e.g. mp4 file, though I'm not sure if this would be available in Ubuntu repository: https://github.com/baresip/baresip/blob/main/modules/avformat/avformat.c#L34.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! So you need to edit the config file for this (/home/user/.baresip/config). In the config file also uncomment the "module aufile.so" and the audio codec modules. 
Baresip will give "file not found" errors even though the issue is an unsupported audio format. This ffmpeg command creates a suitable file:
`ffmpeg -i wire.wav -ac 1 -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_s16le wire2.wav`